# Can One Check that Rafael JS Canvas.paper.set() is not empty

Tags: javascript, svg

Under some circumstances, I would like to pop() Canvas.paper.set() but only if it is not empty.  Is there a way to check how many elements it contains or at least that the number is not zero?  I checked the Rafael reference and could find any info. about that.

Comment: Can't you just call `pop` and see if anything is returned?

Answer (score 0):

`set` has a `length` property that will tell you how many elements it contains.

```
someset.length
```